# Run a jar for specific emails in Outlook

Tags: java, vba, outlook

I have to run some java code every time I receive a specific email. 
I just download the attachment in the email, run the jar and reply with the response from executing that jar with the attachment.

Is it possible to somehow automate this ?

I have checked out VBA routines that can be called using outlook rules but I am not sure whether I can execute my jar file with this.

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289444/how-to-call-java-jar-file-from-excel-vba and https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/775383-running-jar-visual-basic-applications.html
And yeah rules seems to be a good trigger, it only depend of the parameters you want to trigger the code! ;) I just don't know if/how you can pass the result of your jar to VBA again to fill the response

Comment: Going deeper, apparently, you can redirect the output of the jar into a log file, then you could read it from VBA! Look into the comments of the SO question I already linked! ;)

Comment: Thanks, it does look like that might just do what I want. Time to learn VB now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the structure, I'll let you tune it!

You can set a rule to use `SaveToDiskAndReply` which is the main program.

Paste this at the start of your Outlook module :

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub RunSleep( _
                    exec As WshExec, _
                    Optional timeSegment As Long = 800 _
                    )
    Do While exec.Status = WshRunning
        Sleep timeSegment
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function RunProgram( _
                            program As String, _
                            Optional command As String = "" _
                            ) As WshExec
    Dim wsh As New WshShell
    Dim exec As WshExec

    Set exec = wsh.exec(program)
    Call exec.StdIn.WriteLine(command)
    Call RunSleep(exec)
    Set RunProgram = exec
End Function

Public Function Run_Jar() As String
    Dim program As WshExec
    Dim value As String
    '''Set the path (jar and log)
    Set program = RunProgram("java -jar ""D:\\Demo.jar"" 8861ccd621")
    DoEvents
    Run_Jar = program.StdOut.ReadAll
 End Function
```

And use that as the script launched by the rule :

```
Public Sub SaveToDiskAndReply(ItM As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttS As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oItM As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    Dim JarReturn As String

    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    saveFolder = "c:\temp\"
    Set oAttS = ItM.Attachments

    '''Save the attachements
    For Each objAtt In oAttS
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.FileName
    Next objAtt

    '''Run your jar
    JarReturn = Run_Jar

    '''Fill the email
    Set oItM = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    '''Decomment the next line when you're done testing
    'On Error Resume Next
    With oItM
        .To = ItM.SenderEmailAddress
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ItM.Subject
        .Body = JarReturn
        For Each objAtt In oAttS
            .Attachments.Add saveFolder & objAtt.FileName
        Next objAtt
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set oAttS = Nothing
    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will take some time to understand it.

Comment: Will both parts of the code be present in a single module ?

Comment: @adirohan : As `Public Function Run_Jar` is `Public` and it is the only one called from the main program, you can have them in 2 separate modules! ;)